# Why does document.activeElement not point to the focused element in JSDom when testing a Vue component with Jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, jsdom

I'm testing a Vue.js 2 component using `vue-test-utils` and `jest`. This component sets the focus to a specific element automatically. JSDom should point to this element in the `document.activeElement` variable, but even if I set the focus manually inside the test using `wrapper.find(...).element.focus()`, it only ever points to the body element.

```js
it('focuses the default option automatically', async () => {
  const wrapper = await mount(component);
  console.log(document.activeElement); // -> <body></body>
  // expect(document.activeElement.value).toBe('none');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mount a component using vue-test-utils, it is not connected to JSDom automatically. You need to connect it using the [`attachTo`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachto) option of the `mount() / shallowMount()` function.

```js
const wrapper = await mount(component, {
  attachTo: document.body, // ← added!
});
```

What eventually tipped me off was this issue in the enzymejs repository: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2337#issuecomment-586583502

Also, regarding focus, there are issues with specific versions of JSDom (v16 works fine for me) and under some circumstances, the `tabindex` attribute is required: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2586